# Templates in default group not displaying unless group name is in the URL

Tags: ee2, templates, url

I have a set of templates in my default template group called "home".
These templates are "about", "contact-us", "membership" and of course "index".

Only the "index" template will display without the name of the group in the url.
PASS: example.com/
PASS: example.com/home/about
FAIL: (404) example.com/about
PASS: example.com/membership
FAIL: (404) example.com/home/membership

I have tested this with and without an "index.php" .htaccess re-write. No luck.

(Details: Brand new EE 2.6.1 install on stable cPanel server.)

I've never seen this happen before.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is as a result of the Strict URLs feature being [enabled by default in EE2.6+](http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.6-and-strict-urls) (previously it was opt-in, now it's opt-out).

If you want the old behaviour back you can change it in [Global Template Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/global_template_preferences.html#strict-urls)

Comment: I just came across the exact same issue. Thanks foe the answer!